# User Interface Freezes While Loading and App Crashes Frequently

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have nearly completed development on my app. The app is quitting at random points and the user interface freezes/loads very slowly. The app was made without ARC and I am just getting started with using Xcode Instruments to fix memory issues. I am considering moving the entire project to ARC, but don't know if that will help. Also, many of the processes that Instruments Allocations is picking up don't appear to be taking up too much memory.

I need to figure out the best way of improving the efficiency of my app. I have little knowledge in the area and have read a variety of tutorials on how to do certain things to improve efficiency, I just don't know where to start. Should I convert to ARC? Should I focus on using the Allocations/Leaks/Profile Instruments from within Xcode? I know its probably specific to my app, I just don't know where to begin. Any general advice would be great! Thank you all!

Comment: ARC doesn't speed anything up.  For a truly responsive interface, you should be moving processing into the background.

Comment: so instead of calling my JSON feeds/other processes in viewdidappear and viewdidload, I should make custom methods?

Comment: More than that.  Apple has made it trivial to process in the background.  You can use GCD on the low end, and NSThread and NSOperation on the high end.  The hard part is choosing which one you want to implement (or using a mix, just remember standard resource access rules with threads).

Comment: Hi @Brandon, could be please post log message, when the app is quitting. If app doesn't post any log message and quits it could be of memory leaks, please make a copy of project and convert it to ARC and try again.

Comment: Thanks all, looks like this is a bit more complicated than anticipated. I have LOTS of web calls that are being called in viewdidload and viewdidappear. I have not done anything special to make these "asynchronous" I expect that is contributing to the lack of responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to ARC is not got to help you, instead of this focus on Allocations/Leaks. Also try to optimize you code if doing something again and again. Also if you are using synchronous web-service call it also freezes the app.

Comment: Thanks will. Is there a standard way of going about making synchronous web-service calls asynchronous? Or is it something I just need to go about researching?

Comment: For Async Web Request, I'd suggest using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). However this project requires ARC to work.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not something very large, I advice you to move the project to ARC. Using ARC solves lots of developer mistakes in terms of memory.

When we have ARC, why not use it?

And the other thing is, if there are time taking processes. Perform them in a background thread.